# Insert Data into an existing SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I'm having problems inserting data into an existing SQL Server table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Coinmarketcap.dbo.tbl_ATR', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE Coinmarketcap.dbo.tbl_ATR;   

SELECT
    [Ticker],[Date],[px_high], [px_low], [px_close],[yest_close],
    ATR_spd = iif([px_high] > yest_close, [px_high], yest_close) - iif([px_low] > yest_close, yest_close, [px_low]),
    ATR1 = (iif([px_high] > yest_close, [px_high], yest_close) - iif([px_low] > yest_close, yest_close, [px_low])) / (iif(yest_close = 0 , 1 , yest_close))
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, yest_close = lag([px_close]) OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY [Date])
     FROM 
         [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[daily_data]) t
INTO 
    [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[tbl_ATR]
ORDER BY 
    [Ticker] ASC, [Date] DESC
```

I cannot figure out where to place the `INTO` statement.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Also tried `INSERT INTO` statement to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little off... and you don't need an order by since you are dropping the table and it's stored as an unordered set (since you don't have indexes applied here). I assume you want to inherit the definition from the results. This is by using `SELECT ... INTO TABLE ... FROM TABLE` as opposed to `INSERT INTO TABLE ... SELECT ... FROM TABLE`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Coinmarketcap.dbo.tbl_ATR', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE Coinmarketcap.dbo.tbl_ATR; 

SELECT
    [Ticker],
    [Date],
    [px_high], 
    [px_low], 
    [px_close],
    [yest_close],
    ATR_spd = iif([px_high] > yest_close, [px_high], yest_close) - iif([px_low] > yest_close, yest_close, [px_low]),
    ATR1 = (iif([px_high] > yest_close, [px_high], yest_close) - iif([px_low] > yest_close, yest_close, [px_low])) / (iif(yest_close = 0 , 1 , yest_close))
INTO [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[tbl_ATR]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        yest_close = lag([px_close]) OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[daily_data]
) t
```

Note, you can't do...

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT FROM SomeTable
```

Without first explicitly creating that table. I used `SELECT INTO` above since you are dropping the table prior to the statement.